# Zooming, panning & interactive graphical Android app

Tags: android, vector, zooming, graphic, pan

I'm new to android game development. I currently working on a simple android app with zooming, panning and interactive (clickable button) interface. I think it is something similar with Angry bird in some ways.

There are couple of concepts I would like know. Hope you guys can show me some pointer to start with.

1. I've been searching and reading in the Internet. Is openGL the technology I can use?
2. Is the graphic used in such app (e.g. angry bird) vector based graphic? The reason I ask  is that I wish to zoom into certain level and do some panning. I have to draw the object from scratch.

It is rather a vague question and I still figure out the right direction to start with. 
Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out [andengine](http://www.andengine.org/), it is very easy to use and should have everything you need.

Comment: Thanks @Theblacknight. Maybe I should be more specific about my question so that the idea is much clearer presented. Given a problem as below:

1. I have a diagram on the page. The diagram is the only thing on the page. I can zoom in and zoom out the diagram. When it is zoomed in, I could pan around.

2. Objects on the diagram are click-able. When the object is clicked, diagram changes (collapse/expands of the objects).

As I understand from the problem is that, the diagram isn't static, I can't use bitmap and normal zooming mechanism.

Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: I think andengine should work here. It is built on OpenGL, and so you have full control over a camera. Which means you can render what ever you want, to any coordinates, and move the camera around. You would also be able to zoom in/out, and render whatever custom items to the screen. Andengine will also take care of touch detection, and can handle animations and various modifiers (alpha, rotation, translation..). It will basically take away the headache of dealing with Androids surface view, and lower level OpenGL, while providing a lot of handy utilities.

Comment: I just got some times recently to setup AndEngine to try out the example and I realized that PinchZoomExample is everything I need! Panning, zooming and interactive features are in single example! Done! Thank @Theblacknight very much!